# Laravel 6 groupBy to belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-translatable

Hello I have Post model with relation:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(category::class);
}
```

I need show posts on every tab of category. For this I need use groupBy. When I do this:

```
$posts = Post::with('category')->groupBy('category.title')->get();
```

I get error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category.title'.
```

Why? How I can return my posts with key of category title?

For multilangual I use this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

Comment: show the rsults of `Post::with('category')->groupBy('category.title')->dd()` probably your table name is `categories`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Collection's group-by](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby) method:

```php
$posts = Post::with('category')->get()->groupBy('category.title')->all();
```

You may pass a callback to return the value you wish to key the group by (as you mentioned you are using laravel-translatable package):

```php
$posts = Post::with('category')->get()->groupBy(function ($post, $key) {
    return $post->category->getTranslation('title', 'fr');
})->all();
```

Comment: Not work, because I use this: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable in title I have a json.

Comment: @MafysGrif would you please edit your question and add a code to show how you use `laravel-translatable` package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$posts = Post::all()->groupBy('category_id')->get();
```

and then in blade files you can foreach tabs and find a name by category_id